# length in object returns strange value

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this, taken from the console:

```
[1: 1, 31: 0]
length: 32
```

Here an image of it (taken from the console in chrome)

[image]

Having an array like this:

```
var array = ["foo", "bar", "foobar"]
```

and using **length** on that, yields the correct answer: 3

```
console.log(array.length); // returns 3
```

Can someone please tell my, why the length is 32? I checked the several SO-questions and I know, that for my desired value, I'd need to this:

`var i = Object.keys(fragenStatusArray).length; // returns 2`

But I still don't understand why the **length** is 32. Isn't length counting the elements? Is it simply taking the highest numerical index and adds the former ones? Both are of the type `Object` when inspecting it.

Comment: [*JavaScript arrays are zero-indexed: the first element of an array is at index 0, and the last element is at the index equal to the value of the array's length property minus 1.*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: Keep in mind your code is equivalent to `var ary = new Array(32); ary[1] = 1; ary[31] = 0;` It is not the same as `var ary = [ null, 1, 0 ];` which would be length 3, and maybe what you intended.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `length` of an array is one higher than the highest array index property name.

Since you have a property `31`, the `length` is `32`.

---

The [relevant section of the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4) is:

> Array objects give special treatment to a certain class of property
>   names. A property name P (in the form of a String value) is an array
>   index if and only if ToString(ToUint32(P)) is equal to P and
>   ToUint32(P) is not equal to 232−1. A property whose property name is
>   an array index is also called an element.

So if the property name is a number, it is an array index.

> Every Array object has a
>   length property whose value is always a nonnegative integer less than
>   232. The value of the length property is numerically greater than the name of every property whose name is an array index;

And you add 1 to the biggest array index to get the length.

> whenever a
>   property of an Array object is created or changed, other properties
>   are adjusted as necessary to maintain this invariant. Specifically,
>   whenever a property is added whose name is an array index, the length
>   property is changed, if necessary, to be one more than the numeric
>   value of that array index; and whenever the length property is
>   changed, every property whose name is an array index whose value is
>   not smaller than the new length is automatically deleted. This
>   constraint applies only to own properties of an Array object and is
>   unaffected by length or array index properties that may be inherited
>   from its prototypes.

and the length changes whenever it needs to to keep it right.

Comment: So, If I would have an array like `5, 10 and 15`, my array-size would be 16?

Comment: @DasSaffe — You can't have two properties with the same name.

Comment: sry, meant: 5, 10, 15

Comment: Then the `length` would be `16`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. Will accept the answer asap. Must have overseen that, sorry for that.